# Update to 2.3.9 - Error executing script RunApp: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling

Tags: grails

I am update grails from 2.3.7 to 2.3.9 and it has error

> Error executing script RunApp:
>   org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling.

Here is run-app --stacktrace --verbose :

> |Loading Grails 2.3.9
>
> |Configuring classpath
>
> .
>
> |Environment set to development
>
> .................................
>
> |Packaging Grails application
>
> ...........
>
> |Compiling 1 source files
>
> [groovyc] Compiling 1 source file to
>   Z:\future13_grails\cerp\target\classes
>
> .....................................Error
>
> |
>
> Error executing script RunApp:
>   org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling
>
> at
>   org.grails.plugins.tomcat.TomcatServer.(TomcatServer.groovy:81)
>
> at
>   org.grails.plugins.tomcat.InlineExplodedTomcatServer.(InlineExplodedTomcatServer.groovy)
>
> at
>   org.grails.plugins.tomcat.TomcatServerFactory.createInline(TomcatServerFactory.groovy:38)
>
> at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.container.GrailsProjectRunner.runInline(GrailsProjectRunner.groovy:183)
>
> at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.container.GrailsProjectRunner.runApp(GrailsProjectRunner.groovy:119)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.container.GrailsProjectRunner$runApp$0.call(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>
> at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>
> ...
>
> Error | Error executing script RunApp:
>   org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling

And here is BuildConfig.groovy

> ... plugins {
>           // plugins for the build system only
>           build ':tomcat:7.0.52.1'
>
> ```
>     // plugins for the compile step
>     compile ':scaffolding:2.0.3'
>     compile ':cache:1.1.1'
>     compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC2"
>     compile ":searchable:0.6.6"
>
>     // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
>     runtime ':hibernate:3.6.10.15' // ':hibernate4:4.3.5.3' for Hibernate 4
>     runtime ':database-migration:1.4.0'
>     runtime ":jquery:1.10.2"
>     runtime ':resources:1.2.8'
>     // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
>     //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0.1"
>     //runtime ":cached-resources:1.1"
>     //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"
>     runtime ":cors:1.1.2"
> } ...
> ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I deleted target folder and run grails, it run successfully.

Comment: how did you delete the target folder?

Answer (score 1):

If deleting the target folder doesn't work for your, use the clean and compile commands before trying to run your project again.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question [Groovy ShortTypeHandling ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846709/groovy-shorttypehandling-classnotfoundexception).

I doubt any of the plugin's version is only compatible with Grails version `2.4.0` and above (which comes with Groovy `2.3.*`).