# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling

Tags: maven, groovy, plugins

I am running mvn clean install with the following plugin versionsjava  1.8
maven.compiler.source 1.8,maven.compiler.target 1.8,groovy.version 2.4.4,groovy-eclipse-compiler version 2.9.0-01,groovy-eclipse-batch version 2.3.4-01,plexus-compiler api version 2.2,allure version 1.4.16,maven version 3.1.1,surefire version 2.18.1

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>            
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0-01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4-01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-compiler-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

I am not sure what to do now.  Answers from stackoverflow like [Groovy ShortTypeHandling ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846709/groovy-shorttypehandling-classnotfoundexception) did not help me.

Comment: Can you share the code that is reporting this error?  Just to be sure...are you importing this class into your groovy class?

Comment: I am running maven clean install and the error is popping.I am new to maven and not sure about this "are you importing this class into your groovy class".Above mentioned is my plugin and dependencies used.Can you explain how to import?

Comment: Where is this problem actually coming from?  You must be running some code that you wrote.  What you have shared here is your dependency list, but not your actual code.

Comment: **mvn clean install** is the command am running which downloads all the dependencies I have in my pom.xml and validates them against my java code.My java code is developed using 1.7 whic has  ShortTypeHandling support for groovy .But when I upgraded to java 1.8 and ran mvn clean install it is throwing the shown error .Am sure it is version mismatch between java and groovy but cannot find solution.Hope you got the point now

Comment: any one to help??